# how to apply canvas tag on the whole window of my page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, canvas

I wanted to add background to my page with a LinearGradient using canvas tag  so , can anyone help me out?

I used

```
<script>
(function () {
    var c = document.getElementById('canvas'),
        context = c.getContext('2d');

    window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);

    function resizeCanvas() {
        c.width = window.innerWidth;
        c.height = window.innerHeight;
        drawin();
    }
    resizeCanvas();

    function drawin() {
        var rg = c.createLinearGradient(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
        rg.addColorStop(0, blue);
        rg.addColorStop(0, white);
        c.fillStyle = rg;
        c.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
        c.fillStroke(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    })();
```

Comment: Why do you want to have a canvas just for gradient background. Try this http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ .

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help centre. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it will be for users to help you.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

CSS

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0;}

body, html { height:100%; }

canvas {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: works but don't do it with css: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21597456/bad-quality-for-100-both-width-and-height-of-canvas#answer-21597544